CSP Configuration in Rails with Chartkick
Unable to Set Content Security Policy for Specific Controller Action in Rails with Chartkick
Problem Description
I'm trying to configure Content Security Policy (CSP) in my Rails application, which uses Chartkick for charting. I want to allow inline styles only for a specific controller action, following Chartkick's CSP documentation. However, I'm encountering issues with the style-src configuration.
What I've Tried
I attempted to set the style-src configuration for a specific controller action like this:
content_security_policy(only: :show) do |policy|
  policy.style_src :self, :https, :unsafe_inline
end

Error Message
This results in the following error:
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-RyFAsX/0gNRkfaZ4IkA2yvg=='". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

Current Workaround
The only configuration that works is setting unsafe-inline for all style-src directives, which is less secure:
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.default_src :self, :https
  policy.font_src :self, :https, :data
  policy.img_src :self, :https, :data
  policy.object_src :none
  policy.script_src :self, :https
  policy.style_src :self, :https, :unsafe_inline
end

Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_generator = ->(request) { SecureRandom.base64(16) }
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_directives = %w[script-src]

Question
How can I configure the Content Security Policy to allow inline styles only for a specific controller action without compromising security for the rest of the application? Is there a way to override or disable nonce generation for the style-src directive in this specific case?
Additional Context

Rails version: 7.1
Chartkick version: 5.1

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

In theory given this line Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_directives = %w[script-src] a nonce should not be applied to style-src, so your original should work without adding :unsafe_inline to the global policy. I am not recommending this it is just an observation.
